Extract maximal, temperature with corresponding date using the for loop on GEE
I saw code which permitted me to extract maximal temperature from ERA-5 hourly data, so for each hour i have the maximal temperature and corresponding date. Now from this result i want to extract only the maximal temperature and its corresponding date, it is sure i have to use a loop for, but how can i do this?
This is the code
var datasets = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'))
                .select('temperature_2m');
                
var era5_2mt_list = datasets.toList(datasets.size());

print(era5_2mt_list);

var study_area = era5_2mt_list.map(function(img){
  
  var date = ee.Date(ee.Image(img).get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0, 10);
  img = ee.Image(img).subtract(273.15);
  
  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_temp = ee.Image(img)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), zone)
    .get('temperature_2m');
  
  return [date, value_temp];
  
});

var vis2mt = {
  min: -20,
  max: -10,
  palette: [
    '#000080', '#0000D9', '#4000FF', '#8000FF', '#0080FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF80',
    '#80FF00', '#DAFF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFF500', '#FFDA00', '#FFB000', '#FFA400',
    '#FF4F00', '#FF2500', '#FF0A00', '#FF00FF'
  ]
};

var image = ee.Image(era5_2mt_list.get(0))
  .subtract(273.15)
  .clip(zone);

print(image);

Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image, vis2mt);

print(study_area);

